# True or False: Continuous Functions (Extreme Value Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Do my justifications seem appropriate?

**a.)** Every function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a maximum.

True; if $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ wil be closed and bounded above, so it will have a maximum.

**b.)** Every continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a maximum.

True; if $f$ is continuous on a closed, bounded interval, then it will have a min and a max.

**c.)** Every continuous function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a maximum.

False; $f$ is not on a closed interval.

**d.)** Every continuous function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a bounded image.

False; if $f$ has a vertical asymptote at the $0$ endpoint, the image will be unbounded.

**e.)** If the image of a continuous function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded below, then the function has a minimum.

False; only if the inf$f(D)$ is a functional value.

Comment: Counterexample for a): $x\mapsto \dfrac 1 x$, if $x\neq 0$ and give any value at $0$. Works for c) and d) too. A counterexample for e) is $x\mapsto -x^2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking $f$ was continuous in a), but it doesn't have to be. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the true part(s), you may want to be more precise and refer to specific results. I can't fill in the details for you without knowing more about what class you're in (calculus 1? real analysis? topology?).

Your part (a) is wrong because $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. You can cook up as nasty a function as you want as a counterexample.

For parts (c), (d), and (e), you should probably write down counterexamples. For instance, in (c), you note: "$f$ is not on a closed interval." This is begging the question, because that's more or less what you're being asked to justify. There are many continuous functions on an open interval that *are* bounded, so you should explicitly produce a function on an open interval that is *not* bounded.

Comment: The last paragraph is key.